# Cardinal directions in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I want to show the cardinal direction at top of the map that shows the North direction like (a) section in the image below :
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Which projection will you be using?  That is not a good example, as north should be pointing towards the North Pole.  If you have a global projection where north is at the top in an unrotated view you could customise the rotate control https://codesandbox.io/s/rotation-forked-pmgb2